# What's the difference between using these two formulas to find the equation of a line?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Say we have these two points on a xy plane. (2, 3) and (4, 5). The slope would be 1. To get the equation of the line we can use one of these two formulas.

```
Substitution y and x values in the formula y = mx + c
3 = 2(1) + C
C = 1
y = 1(x) + 1

Using a different formula y - y1 = m(x - x1)
y - 3 = 1(x - 2)
y = 1(x) + 1
```

Both of them produce the same results. Is there a scenario where one should be use the other?

Comment: Short answer, no, these are always equally easy and useful.  For a different formula, the *normal form* of the equation of a line (rather than slope-intercept as above) is often useful when distances from a point to the line are to be found.

Comment: In both cases what you are really doing is $\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$ given the two points on the line $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. You cheated a bit by not showing how you got the slope $m$ in each case.

Comment: i think how a same function can have different representation would be of interest to you, look up analytic continuation, this is good question,

Comment: You cannot compare the two formulas, as one computes `y` and the other `y-y1`. You should write the second as `y=m(x-x1)+y1` and it is immediate that they coincide with `c=y1-m.x1` (except for the number of operations and possible truncation errors in numerical computation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are essentially the same.

The second equation is $y - y_1 = m(x-x_1)$. Rearranging the terms, we can get $y = mx + (y_1 -mx_1) = mx + C$ where $C = (y_1 -mx_1)$, which then we obtain the first equation.

Answer (score 0):

You even may know by heart the *interpolation formula*:
$$y=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)+y_1,$$
which is valid if $x_1\neq x_2$ (trivial case).

Answer (score 0):

yes, there are situations where these can be different, for example in programming multiplying by 0.0000001 is faster than dividing by 10000000.

number of operations and type of operations matter, even if the all the values obtained are the same, one can come up with definitions so that the representations can be put into separate categories.